# How to get point depth in shadow space for point light?

Tags: opengl, glsl, shadow-mapping

I'm implementing exponential shadow maps, and so far I have directional lights and spotlights working perfectly.  Currently I'm trying to apply this technique to point lights with cubemapped shadows.

The theory is, the visibility factor should be computed as a product of two exponentials:

```
visibility = exp(k*occluderDepth) * exp(-k*receiverDepth)
```

So the shadow map, instead of storing depth, stores exp(k*occluderDepth), and the lighting pass multiplies this value by exp(-k*receiverDepth).

My shadowmap renderer looks like this:

```
//vsh
#version 410

uniform mat4 viewProjectionMatrix;
uniform mat4 modelTransform;

in vec4  position;

void main (void) {
    gl_Position = viewProjectionMatrix * modelTransform * position;
}

//fsh
#version 410

float lightExponentialConstant = 200.0;

layout (location = 0) out float exponentialMapVaule;

void main (void) {
    exponentialMapVaule = exp(lightExponentialConstant * map_01(gl_FragCoord.z, lightNearPlane, lightFarPlane));
}
```

The visibility for spot and directional lights is computed like so and it works perfectly:

```
uniform sampler2D shadowmapSampler;
uniform mat4 shadowSpaceProjection;

float map_01(float x, float v0, float v1) {
  return (x - v0) / (v1 - v0);
}

float computeVisibility(vec3 position) { 

    mat4 shadowBias = mat4(
        0.5, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
        0.0, 0.5, 0.0, 0.0,
        0.0, 0.0, 0.5, 0.0,
        0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0
    );

    vec4 shadowCoord =  shadowBias * shadowSpaceProjection * vec4(position, 1.0);
    float occluder = texture(shadowmapSampler, shadowCoord.xy/shadowCoord.w).r;
    float reciever = map_01(shadowCoord.z/shadowCoord.w, lightNearPlane, lightFarPlane);
    float visibility = clamp(occluder * exp(-lightExponentialConstant * reciever), 0.0, 1.0);

    return visibility;

}
```

So basically the `receiver` value is the depth of the world position projected into shadow space, and then mapped to the range [0, 1] according to the offset of that point from the shadow projection's near plane and far plane.

I have tried to apply the same logic to the cubemap shadowmap for my point light:

```
float map_01(float x, float v0, float v1) {
  return (x - v0) / (v1 - v0);
}

uniform samplerCube shadowCubemap;

float computeVisibility(vec3 position, vec3 lightPosition) {

    vec3 ray = position - lightPosition;
    float distance = length(ray);
    float occluder = texture(shadowCubemap, normalize(ray)).r;
    float receiver = map_01(distance, lightNearPlane, lightFarPlane);
    float visibility = clamp(occluder * exp(-lightExponentialConstant * reciever), 0.0, 1.0);

    return visibility;

}
```

So here, if I understand correctly, `distance` should be the length of the vector between the world position and the light position (which should be equivalent to the reprojected depth from the 2D example).  But *everything* is occluded when I use this method.

What am I missing?  In particular, I'm not sure if I am not confident about the cubemap sampling, or if I'm missing some step to ensure that the `distance` value used to compute the `receiver` value is actually being transformed correctly to shadow space.